# FLareget wont show any file on the list after reboot

Tags: 12.04, download-manager

I am using flare-get as download manager on my Ubuntu 12.10 OS. I am downloading a large file for a long time. Due to some reason in the middle of download i had to restart my PC. I pause my running download and restart it and after that I couldn't find any file on it's list. I don't know why. It happens all the time. Is there any problem on settings? Or how could I resume that one.

Comment: Is this an FTP download? Or HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any issue with resuming. I hope you are using the latest version. You can try **exiting the flareget** before restarting your PC.

**Please note: This website is not meant for particular software related issues. Most of the applications provide their own support. The better place to ask this question will be** [Report FlareGet Issues](http://flareget.com/blog/2013/04/report-bugs-flareget-1-4-7stable/)

Comment: OK. I got it. It's another bug issue and they fixed it on the latest version released 1 day ago.